# Shell Command to extract a value from an xml file into the Shell script

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xmllint

I have the following xml text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<buildinfo xmlns:xsi="http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.w3.org&#x2f;2001&#x2f;XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;abc.com&#x2f;schema&#x2f;4.0&#x2f;buildinfo" xsi:schemaLocation="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;abc.com&#x2f;schema&#x2f;4.0&#x2f;buildinfo https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;abc.com&#x2f;resource&#x2f;4.0&#x2f;buildinfo.xsd" buildinfo_version="1" account_id="23456" app_id="456321" sandbox_id="223457" build_id="1234567">    
<build version="1 Jul 2016 Static" build_id="1234567" submitter="David" platform="Not Specified" lifecycle_stage="Not Specified" results_ready="true" scan_overdue="false" legacy_scan_engine="false">
  <analysis_unit analysis_type="Static" published_date="2016-07-1T15&#x3a;58&#x3a;55-04&#x3a;00" published_date_sec="324532678" status="Results Ready" engine_version="2341267"/>
</build>
</buildinfo>
```

I have a shell script that requires the build_id from this file, (build_id constantly changes). How do I extract the "build_id" value from this file into a variable in that script.

Answer (score 0):

xmlstarlet is useful for querying XML files

example:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'buildinfo' sample.xml

Output: 
buildinfo 
buildinfo/build 
buildinfo/build/analysis_unit
```

More information : http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html

Comment: I don't seem to get any output when I use the above mentioned command. :(

Comment: Please check your installation, I tried it in MacOS and it works fine.